# How to add discounts for unsold products in magento

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9. I have more than 1000 products, but many products are in unsold. So for promotion, I need to add discount for those unsold products.

In promotions we can add Product discount and Shopping cart rule. But for unsold products there are no option to add discount..

Any one how to add it from admin panel.?